# C# event cannot call anonymous method with the correct argument value

Tags: c#, events, delegates, anonymous-function

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    Roption.DropDownItems.Add(string.Concat("Item &", i), null, delegate { Reset(i); });
```

where `Reset()` is called when the dropdown item is clicked.

The problem is that no matter which dropdown item is clicked, the argument passed to `Reset` is 7 (the value of `i` after the loop terminates), not the value of `i` when the `Roption.DropDownItems.Add` function is called. What causes this behavior and how can it be fixed? (I don't really want to hard code 0 through 6 in seven otherwise identical statements).

Comment: Make a copy of variable `i` like this `i1 = i` and pass `i1` to reset method instead... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp

Comment: That works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that when you are creating the delegates in a loop, all objects will be passed by reference. This means that regardless of whether they are value-type or reference-type objects, they will still get passed by reference.

So what does this mean for your code? Well, as the loop iterates through, all of the `Reset` method calls that have a copy of `i` have a reference to the same one. So, as the value of `i` increases, so does the value for every single reference.

[Closures Explained](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)